# How to increment the last octet in an IP address

Tags: ruby

How to write a ruby helper function which will increment from `222.164.153.58 to 222.164.153.59` or increment the 3rd octet properly if it hits the max on the 4th octet.

Comment: We expect you to show us the code you've written and explain why it didn't work. Stack Overflow isn't a "give me code" site, it's a "please help me fix my code" site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`IPAddr#succ`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-succ).

```
require "ipaddr"

addr = IPAddr.new "222.164.153.58"
addr.succ
#=> #<IPAddr: IPv4:222.164.153.59/255.255.255.255>

addr = IPAddr.new "192.168.2.255"
addr.succ
#=> #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.3.0/255.255.255.255>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ipaddr`objects have a `succ` method

```
require "ipaddr"
ip = IPAddr.new("222.164.153.58")

5.times{puts ip; ip = ip.succ}

#222.164.153.58
#222.164.153.59
#222.164.153.60
#222.164.153.61
#222.164.153.62
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increment by more than one, succ isn't super helpful because you have to do it in a loop. Say you want to calculate the upper and lower of 3000 addresses:

```
require 'ipaddr'
lower = IPAddr.new('10.0.0.0')
upper = IPAddr.new(lower.to_i + 3000, Socket::AF_INET)
```

Then you can iterate them like so:

```
for ip in lower..upper
  # Do something with ip
end
```